# Not able to deserialise a json to yang using pyangbind json decoder

Tags: python

I am trying to deserialise a json which is a valid format w.r.to the yang model defined. This example is given in the pyangbind documentation. But the json format is a little different from what I pasted here.

https://github.com/robshakir/pyangbind/tree/master/docs/example/simple-serialise

JSON:

```
{
    "a-container": {
        "a-value": 8
    },
    "a-list": [
        {
            "the-key": "entry-one"
        },
        {
            "the-key": "entry-two"
        }
    ]
}
```

Yang:

```
    module simple_serialise {
        yang-version "1";
        namespace "http://rob.sh/yang/examples/ss";
        prefix "ss";

        container a-container {
            leaf a-value {
                type int8;
            }
        }

        list a-list {
            key 'the-key';
            leaf the-key {
                type string;
            }
        } 
   }
```

I tried to deserialise with:

```
from pyangbind.lib import pybindJSON

from lib import simple_serialise

s = '''{
    "a-container": {
        "a-value": 8
    },
    "a-list": [
        {
            "the-key": "entry-one"
        },
        {
            "the-key": "entry-two"
        }
    ]
}'''
sip = pybindJSON.loads(s, simple_serialise, 'simple_serialise')
```

I get the following error when I try to deserialise.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joshisk/PycharmProjects/tapi-pyang/src/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    sip = pybindJSON.loads(di1, simple_serialise, 'simple_serialise') #type: simple_serialise.simple_serialise
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyangbind/lib/pybindJSON.py", line 58, in loads
    path_helper=path_helper, extmethods=extmethods, overwrite=overwrite)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyangbind/lib/serialise.py", line 302, in load_json
    key_order = d[key].keys()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: "But the json format is a little different from what I pasted here." Why not pasting the code you have the problem with?

Comment: I added more info. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyangbind expects a dictionary with the key as the 'key' value you gave in the model.

```
list a-list {
    key 'the-key';
```

In your case, the value for 'the-key'.

```
from pyangbind.lib import pybindJSON

from lib import simple_serialise

s = '''{
    "a-container": {
        "a-value": 8
    },
    "a-list": {
        "entry-one": {
            "the-key": "entry-one"
        },
        "entry-two": {
            "the-key": "entry-two"
        }
    }
}'''
sip = pybindJSON.loads(s, simple_serialise, 'simple_serialise')
```